# PHP shorthand IF with two variables in the first part

Tags: php

How can I write this IF condition (at the moment I have error, but I don't know where)?

```
$gll_name = ($gll_id != NULL ? $w = $this->gallery_model->gallery_get_one_user($gll_id);  $w->name : " ");
```

Comment: The error is in the `;` after the function call. You can only have one expression in that clause

Comment: Please, please, please... learn to write if statements longhand, especially  if they look completely unintelligible (and don't work) when you try using the ternary operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need two variables, also "shorthand ifs" do not allow colons. This should work:

```
$gll_name = (
    $gll_id != NULL
    ? $this->gallery_model->gallery_get_one_user($gll_id)->name
    : " ");
```

(note that I have added indents for visibility, they do not matter in PHP in this case)

Also consider **strict conditions** (using `!==` instead of `!=`), as PHP will treat all false-ish values (`null`, `false`, `0` etc.) as being equal (`==`) to `NULL`, but only `NULL` is strictly equal (`===`) to `NULL`. For a demonstration see: http://ideone.com/8ENsX

Comment: I take your word for it that it should work, but a much better suggestion would be "do not attempt code that you cannot immediately understand". Splitting the expression should be the first option here.

Comment: @Jon: I agree that you should not write code you do not understand, but what did you mean by "_splitting the expression_"?

Comment: @Tadeck: Using more than one expression (e.g. here an if/else) to bring down the length and complexity of the single one the OP gives.

Comment: @Jon: Maybe the better idea would be to use explicit `if` statement instead. The only difference is visibility. But this case is rather so simple, it does not necessarily require separation into `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do does not make sense. You have to start with the assignment operator as in

```
 $gll_name =
```

Then put your condition with a question mark afterwards eg

```
 (1 == 1 && 2 == 2) ?
```

Then the value if true : and value if false eg

```
'correct' : 'not good' ;
```

Equalling

```
  $gll_name =  (1 == 1 && 2 == 2) ?  'correct' : 'not good' ;
```